# Email stamp on original email

Tags: excel, vba

hi have a code whereby it first finds a duplicate from Sheet 3 to sheet 2 and then it removes the duplicate from sheet2 however is there a way also to add email stamp on original email and also removes the duplicate from sheet2 using the stamp?

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateRows()
Dim ur1 As Range, ur2 As Range, dupeRows As Range
Dim r1 As Range, s1 As String, r2 As Range, s2 As String

Set ur1 = Worksheets("EmailsSent").UsedRange.Rows
Set ur2 = Worksheets("EmailReport").UsedRange.Rows  'Find duplicates from Sheet1 in Sheet2

Set dupeRows = ur2(Worksheets("EmailReport").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
For Each r1 In ur1
    s1 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r1)))
    For Each r2 In ur2
        s2 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r2)))
        If s1 = s2 Then
            If Intersect(dupeRows, r2) Is Nothing Then
                Set dupeRows = Union(dupeRows, r2)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

dupeRows.EntireRow.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you clearly define what that "email stamp" should mean?

Comment: oh for an visual inspection on sheet(EmailsSent) for Audit purposes and also prior to sending out an email from Sheet2(EmailReport) should pick this up and avoid sending out an email with msg No new Due date to send email

Comment: I do not care about the purpose... I would only like to understand how to look (the time of running, your name etc.) and where to be placed.

Comment: Hi Sorry, Yes something like in column A is the names, C it is the due date and in column D would be the email stamp perhaps as "Sent". code will need to be placed before the data is being copied from Sheet2 to Sheet 3 as it will check against the name and "Sent" in sheet 3

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want accomplishing... Do you want, besides what the code deletes now, to also delete the reference in the other sheet? The one which did not match the row to be deleted? So, do you need the stamp only like a marker, to remove the lines of the first sheet?

Comment: can i upload an sample book in here as it would be easier to understand what i need to archive. stamp on the one which did not matched the deleted ones

Comment: No need of any workbook, if we cannot agree about what is to be done... So you want the stamp on the others rows, then the one to be deleted, but I am not sure I correctly understood where this to be done... It should happen, probably, in the sheet where the rows are not deleted. Is that correct? If yes, you did not answer my question from the previous comment: **"do you need the stamp only like a marker, to remove the lines of the first sheet"?**

Comment: Yes sorry that is correct, i need stamp only like a marker and to remove the lines from sheet2 call (EmailReport) and stamp will go on sheet 3 (EmailsSent)

Comment: OK. In such a situation, at the first glance, it das not look necessary to use any marker. The range to be deleted in the other sheet should be built during the existing code run. I do not have right now time to put in practice what I have in mind but in less than an hour I will prepare an answer...

Comment: Ok @FaneDuru no problems, many thanks

Comment: I will try making an answer in some minutes. It will not delete anything. It will build the ranges to be deleted and will return their address. You have to check them and only if they mean what you need, you will comment the `Debug.Print` lines and uncomment the ones which really deletes the ranges...

Comment: yh ok no problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateRows()
    Dim ur1 As Range, ur2 As Range, dupeRows As Range, rngMarked As Range
    Dim r1 As Range, s1 As String, r2 As Range, s2 As String, boolFound As Boolean

    Set ur1 = Worksheets("EmailsSent").UsedRange.rows
    Set ur2 = Worksheets("EmailReport").UsedRange.rows  'Find duplicates from Sheet1 in Sheet2

    Set dupeRows = ur2(ur2.rows.count + 1)
    Set rngMarked = ur1(ur1.rows.count + 1)
    For Each r1 In ur1
        s1 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r1)))
        For Each r2 In ur2
            s2 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r2)))
            If s1 = s2 Then
                If Intersect(dupeRows, r2) Is Nothing Then
                    Set dupeRows = Union(dupeRows, r2)
                    boolFound = True 'confirmation that the code found the at least an equal row
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Not boolFound Then  'for rows not having a match, build the range in the second sheet
            If Intersect(rngMarked, r1) Is Nothing Then
                Set rngMarked = Union(rngMarked, r1)
            End If
        End If
        boolFound = False      'reinitialize the variable
    Next

    Debug.Print dupeRows.Address  'this is what your code used to return, anyhow
    Debug.Print rngMarked.Address 'this is what you need
    'dupeRows.EntireRow.Delete
    'rngMarked.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Is it possible to be more occurrences for the same checked row, in the second sheet? I am asking that in order to increase the code speed... If it is only one, the iteration in the second sheet must be exited after finding the match.

Comment: I used your code way of setting the range(s) to be deleted. This way deletes also the first empty range after the last existing one. I usually proceed in a different way: I check if the range `is Nothing` and in such a case the range is set. Only after that I use the `Union` between the existing range and the next ones found during the iteration.

Comment: Hi no it still shows the duplicate after i have changed it to delete.i have changed my question and the code now

Comment: @Harin: Please, edit your question and put on top of it the original code. Then you can write "Edited:" and let somebody else to understand what you want. Otherwise, people seeing my answer will think that I hit my head recently...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru i am sorry i had no any intention to make you upset and also i have replaced my original code with yours as it was better than my original ones as it had option not to delete the rows. once again Thank you and i apology once again as i had no any intention.

Comment: @Harin: I did not imagine that you tried upsetting me, on purpose. But there are some community rules. When a question is answered, you do not replace the presented code with something not related with the original question. If you have something else to clarify, open a new question and ask for help...